# I want to connect a windows machine to a L2TP/ IPsec vpn using python

Tags: windows, winapi, pywin32, ras

I have  a soft-ether VPN server and I want to make a custom client application, which will look like other vpn clients (Nord,Hola vpns) in python. The problem is in python I cannot find a way to use windows built-in  vpn manager to connect via  IPsec protocol programmatically.

In C I can find a RAS API but since I am new to network infrastructure programming so its hard for me to dissolve it properly uderstand how it actually works.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful to you: https://github.com/zentin26/python-vpn.

Comment: Its server I want client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Add-VpnConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnection?view=win10-ps) and [`Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/set-vpnconnectionipsecconfiguration?view=win10-ps)in Windows PowerShell

See the Example 2 in 2nd link:

```
PS C:\> Add-VpnConnection -Name "Contoso" -ServerAddress 176.16.1.2 -TunnelType "L2tp"
PS C:\> Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName "Contoso" -AuthenticationTransformConstants None -CipherTransformConstants AES128 -EncryptionMethod AES128 -IntegrityCheckMethod SHA256 -PfsGroup None -DHGroup ECP256 -PassThru -Force
AuthenticationTransformConstants : None

CipherTransformConstants         : AES128

DHGroup                          : ECP256

IntegrityCheckMethod             : SHA256

PfsGroup                         : None

EncryptionMethod                 : AES128
```

And it should also be simple to call the PowerShell from Python.